# Python Pandas.tests.extension Module Not Found

Tags: python, pandas, module

I'm quite new to python and have been trying to run code for someone's project. However, it kept giving me the ModuleNotFound error message that says - "No module name 'pandas.tests.extension.numpy_' " in the ubuntu terminal.

Inside the code itself, the import statement is

```
from pandas.tests.extension.numpy_.test_numpy_nested import np
```

I do have the pandas module installed. Do you guys know what the issue could be and how to fix this? Thank you

[Terminal and import line screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEBuX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use two import lines

```
import pandas.tests.extension
import numpy_.test_numpy_nested as np
```